# Edit values by condition with kind of "WHERE clause"

Tags: r, where-clause

I would like to edit values in a data frame **with dplyr** by condition and continue with the edited data frame like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  column1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
  column2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
)

df <- df %>% 
  filter(column1 == "B") %>% 
  mutate(column2 = 999)

# df %>% ...
```

The code sample above should generate the data frame and in the section with the pipe operator I would like to edit only the values of "column2" if "column1" == "B" - but because of the filter statement the new data frame "df" is reduced to those rows with "column1" being "B" and the others ("A" and "C"-rows) are gone.

Actually I think of a way similar to the SQL statement "WHERE", f.e.

`UPDATE df SET column2 = 999 WHERE column1 = "B"` > this would lead to the df with the column2 values 1, 2, 999, 999, 5, 6.

I know that this would be possible with the baseR code like this:

```
df$column2[df$column1 == "B"] <- 999
```

but first I like to use dplyr and second sometimes I would like to edit multiple columns so I would have to repeat the code line above multiple times.

I hope I was able to explain what I need.

Thank you!

Comment: You may use `ifelse` or `case_when` i.e. `df <- df %>% mutate(column2 = case_when(column1 == 'B' ~999, TRUE ~ column2))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for my late response!